# Sending of location update to server from android without pressing or using button

Tags: android, button, android-intent, location

I have done series of research and analysis. I couldnt get the right way to do it. So i thought of asking your help. I have two things to ask from you guys.

1)I got the partial answer but your elaborate help is really appreciated. How to start intent from Broadcast receiver to launch another activity. This is what i choose when i thought of launching an activity when a number is dialed. Here is what i got so far.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 

       Intent i = new Intent();
       i.setClassName("com.tsering.project", "com.tsering.project.MainActivity");
       i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(i);
}
```

2) Is there anyway to send data like location updates to server without using or pressing button in android. I want automatic sending of location update to the server.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a locationmanager:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Request location updates (consult developer.android.com for what to use as parameters)

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 50, this);
```

And implement this method to handle location changes. Here you want some code to send data to the server

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: I implemented as you mentioned. But its not working properly. The main thing in my implementation is that i am sending the dialed number as well the location updates during dialing. Its not working at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Basically onReceive() is used to receive broadcast data which are coming from another side.

its may be come from any activity or may be from service through the help of Intent following sendBrodcast(intent) method.

Tim is right, but its a little bit good for you to follow the actual steps. 
Check   [***this link***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095030/background-service-need-to-send-gps-location-on-server?rq=1) .. hope this will give you some better ideas..