# GPS Tracker service class is not getting called in my application

Tags: android, web-services, service, gps, broadcastreceiver

I am working on a gps tracker application. my application should work in the background and should not be visible to the user in the menu.. So basically what happens is it posts the latitude and logitude values in the php server..and my application should manually start and stop from morning 9am to evening 9pm without the interaction with the user..I am using a broadcast receiver and service to make my application run in background i am passing an intent from receiver to service class and the problem is my service class is not getting called

Here is my code.. for Broadcast receiver

```
public class MainActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Toast.makeText(context, "MyReceiver Started"+intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent myIntent=new Intent(context,GPSTRACKER.class);   
    context.startService(myIntent);       
    }}
```

And here is Service code..GPSTRACKER

```
 public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
 private static String url_create_product = "http://testingicon.com/gps.php";  
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
JSONparser1 jsonParser2=new JSONparser1();
private final Context mContext;
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
 boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
boolean canGetLocation = false;
Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude  
double longitude; // longitude
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1;//1 meter
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 5000;//30 
protected LocationManager locationManager;
private static final String TAG = "BroadcastGPSService";
public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.example.gpstracking.display";
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
Intent intent;
int counter = 0;     
int hour,min,year,month,day; 
GeoPoint gp; 
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);  
}
public GPSTracker(Context context) {     
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
    }
public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();}}}
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }}}}}} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}return location;}
     @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  //  handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);     
    super.onDestroy();}
/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);}}
/**  
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();}
    // return latitude
    return latitude;}
/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();}
    // return longitude
    return longitude;} 
/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}
/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    // Setting Dialog Title       
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");
    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }});
    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();}});
    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //getLocation();
    latitude=location.getLatitude();
    longitude=location.getLongitude();
    gp = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1000000), (int)(longitude*1000000));         

    String address = ConvertPointToLocation(gp);
    String locationname = address.substring(0,address.length());  

    Date date = new Date();
     //formatting time to have AM/PM text using 'a' format

    String strDateFormat = "HH:mm:ss a";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);
    String time=sdf.format(date);
    String device_id=getdeviceid(mContext);
    System.out.println("Time with AM/PM field : " + time);

    System.out.println("Location changed is.................. "+latitude+longitude + "Time is  "+time +"Date is  "+date );
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Location changed is.................. "+"Latitude " +latitude+ "Logitude "+longitude + "Time is  "+time +"Date is  "+date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    Log.d(TAG, "entered DisplayLoggingInfo"+ " Time is "+time+ "Date is  "+ date   + "Device Id iss "+device_id );

    String str1=String.valueOf(longitude);   
    String str2=String.valueOf(latitude);

    // here is the code for Posting values on PHP server     
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", str1));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", str2));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", time));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_id", device_id));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location_name", locationname));

    JSONArray json1=jsonParser2.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product, "POST",         params);
    // check log cat fro response
   //   Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
    // check for success tag
   /* try {
        int success = json1.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
             // successfully created product
            // closing this screen
         } else {
            // failed to create product
        }} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}*/
    //db code
}
private String ConvertPointToLocation(GeoPoint gp2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String address = "";
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(gp2.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, gp2.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            for (int index = 0; index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
                address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";}}
    catch (IOException e) {                
        e.printStackTrace();}   
    return address;}
protected String getdeviceid(Context context2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context2.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String deviceId;
        if (manager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE) {
            //Tablet
             deviceId = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        } else {
            //Mobile
             deviceId = manager.getDeviceId();
        }
        return deviceId;
        }
    @Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;}}
```

Here is Manifest file

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             package="com.websmithing.broadcasttest"
                 android:versionCode="1"
         android:versionName="1.0" >
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
 android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <receiver
android:enabled="true"
android:name=".MainActivity">
 <!-- <intent-filter>
    <action android:name = "com.websmithing.broadcasttest.BroadcastService"/>
      </intent-filter>   -->
      </receiver>
       <service android:name=".GPSTRACKER" />
       </application>

        </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

1st : You can use AlarmManager followed by PendingIntent.

OR

Check [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095030/background-service-need-to-send-gps-location-on-server?rq=1) .
Hope it will help you.