# how can i set app continue start in background after close it like as skyps

Tags: android

I make a GPS application and that working fine but the difficulty is that I want to start continue in background like as Facebook and Skype, anybody please help me.

Comment: have a look at android service

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background service need to send GPS location on server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095030/background-service-need-to-send-gps-location-on-server)

Comment: I have two class one is my main class that have start and stop button and another is service class that have GPSTracker. when I call start button startService(new GPSTracker(this)); and for stop  stopService(new GPSTracker()); like this, in minimize it work fine but when I close it from minimize its stop getting location..

Answer (score 1):

You should create a background service like [this](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).

And if you want location updates [here](http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/background-location-updates-on-android) is a blog post about it.