# Do I need service to do something when app is in background?

Tags: android

I have to write an app that is supposed to send user location to server.

I have class that is listening events from Android and it sends data to server bia webservice.

Do I have to put that in some service, or I can just put it into my MainActivity class code?

Im asking, because Android is still weird for me. It pauses activities and I don't know if this will work "from the background" or not.

Of course I want to update location when application is in foreground and background too.

Comment: u need to write a service which is run background even app is closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will have to use a Service to send data in the background as well as foreground.
You can use android Service or Background Service,
based on your requirements I would suggest using the Background Service.

Here are the links for both:

**Service:**

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

**Background Service:**

https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Answer (score 0):

if you want the location irrespective of the fact that the application is open or not then you need to have a service which will keep on posting your location to the server.

Here's how you can do it ...

[Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095030/background-service-need-to-send-gps-location-on-server)

**Note** :

Activities can't do what you want to achieve as they exist till the user exits them (by pressing the back button, killing them or clearing the stack[Need not think of it for now if a newbie]).

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article on android.com website
https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html