# How I can send longitude,latitude and my IP adress to the server using android service?

Tags: java, android, rest

I need an application that will send GPS location and my IP adress every 1 minutes in the background to the server (Spring Roo service).

The application needs to send data even if it is closed. So I created a service.

I have read that you need to put some receiver or something but nothing so far works. So I will be very pleased if someone can help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what you have done so far. show the code

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095030/background-service-need-to-send-gps-location-on-server?rq=1

Comment: Please, any explication about the last Post. thanks