# Get user position (gps) even if app is closed

Tags: android, ios, gps, ionic-framework

I'm deploying an app with Ionic framework. The app basically need to receive push notifications based on (specific) user position. Those notifications are location dependant, so I'm trying to figure out if it's possibile to retrieve current user location without ask the user to run the app.
I know that push notifications are received even if app is not running, what I'd like to do is to show notifications only if the user is in a specific area.
Thanks

Comment: you need a cordova plugin to do this check out those two plugins 




 https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode -------







 https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt

Comment: @AnasOmar thanks for the suggest it seems that is a good start point for what I'm looking for. Do you know why background mode is not store compilant (as stated in the official repo docs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I know that push notifications are received even if app is not running*

That's not true. Push notifications let your application notify a user of new messages or events even **when the user is not actively using your application**, but application must be started and running in background.

You must perform 2 different actions:

- [Execute app on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup) to allow it to perform actions needed.
- [Use GPS in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387294/run-gps-listener-in-background-android) to know when device is in the desired position to notify.

Comment: so basically every app on my smartphone that uses push notifications such as Facebook or Whatsapp always runs in background even if not started by me?

Comment: absolutely yes, check background process to verify

Comment: another thing is: some apps have a little push process that runs in background and this process make notifications, causing app opens when clicked. But something is running in the background always

Comment: what's the deal in doing a separate process? It's for performances / battery drain reason or is there something more? Push notification behaviour is the same for both remote and local notifications?

Comment: More for performance but also battery drain, background process are (even small) battery vampires because they use device resources continously, but a big app opened affects more to performance than a small one,